# jQuery.text() is showing a weird behavior, why?

Tags: jquery

Have a look at the following JS Bin please:

http://jsbin.com/yabevi/edit?html,js,output

I am new to jQuery. Second of the jQuery `.text()` method is not working in this bin, why is it so?

Comment: The Id in html is not correct. id="temp=unit-f"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues:

- First span closing tag is incorrect
- Second span Id is not matching with the selector

http://jsbin.com/gojoyuneyu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="jquery-test">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
        <h1 id="temp">
          <span id="temp-val"></span>
          <span id="temp-unit-c"></span>
          <span id="temp-unit-f"></span>
        </h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid markup. You have not closed first span element. due to which 2nd and 3rd span elements are interpreted as child of first element by browser. and setting `.html()` to first span completely removes them. thus you need to properly close first span element to fix the issue:

```
 <h1 id="temp">
      <span id="temp-val"></span>
      <span id="temp-unit-c"></span>
      <span id="temp=unit-f"></span>
    </h1>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/tenizapire/1/edit?html,js,output)**